Error 400 al registrar un Webhook en aplicacion #linkedin
Tengo un problema al activar el registro de webhook de #linkedin, he intentado de todo tal como esta en la documentacion he ajustado headers y configurado URN codificadas sin embargo al solicitar la suscripcion obtengo este error:
{ "message": "Failed to create subscription. RestException{_response=RestResponse[headers={Content-Length=13373, content-type=application/x-protobuf2; symbol-table="https://ltx1-app92263.prod.linkedin.com:3778/partner-entities-manager/resources|partner-entities-manager-war--60418946", x-restli-error-response=true, x-restli-protocol-version=2.0.0},cookies=[],status=400,entityLength=13373]} ", "status": 400 }
la llamada que estoy realizando es:
curl --location --request PUT 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/eventSubscriptions/(developerApplication:urn%3Ali%3AdeveloperApplication%3A219795302,user:urn%3Ali%3Aperson%3Ad9qwE,entity:urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A10291,eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)' \ --header 'LinkedIn-Version: 202405' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --header 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' \ --header 'Authorization: ••••••' \ --header 'Cookie: lidc="b=TB16:s=T:r=T:a=T:p=T:g=5494:u=1341:x=1:i=1716582567:t=1716661312:v=2:sig=AQGzDlYwcKSrX9-utdno8q"; bcookie="v=2&5c5fe86f-d02c-48dd-855c-16"; Cookie_1=value' \ --data '{ "webhook": "https://webhook.site/7c2b4a-d0bf-411c-96e6-914b" }'
Trabajando la llamada con postman donde los header Content-Length y Host son generados automaticamente. He visto en algunos foros que se debe ingresar a una pestana de webhook en el UI de aplicacion, https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/219795302/Webhooks, sin embargo esta pestaña no es accesible desde mi app y tampoco veo algun procedimiento para solicitar la habilitación de los webhooks. PD: Soy Admin de la página y de la aplicación.
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/linkedin/shared/api-guide/webhook-validation?context=linkedin%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-2024-05
¿Alguna pista de que estoy haciendo mal o como solicitar habilitar la pestaña de webhooks?
"The Webhooks tab is only enabled for applications with a use case for webhooks. For Lead Syncing use cases, webhook subscriptions must be created via the Lead Notification Subscriptions API and cannot be created via the UI"
#linkedin  N.º de caso: 240524-017378

y los permisos???
